# EntityFramework not return any row result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello I'm facing with issue with reading data from DB. I try to build web api in core 6.0 but cannot found where is my error. I also compare it with my web app for users (work with same db) and there request for *ProductHeaders* return value, but in api not.
Maybe something missing in Program.cs ?
Pls any kind of help will be very helpful.

Here is Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions,BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication",null);


var services=builder.Services;
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
                
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IProductManager,ProductManager>();
    services.AddScoped<IProductHeaderRepository,ProductHeaderRepository>();
    
}
var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

now simple controller for first test

```
namespace RecipesApi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProductionController : ControllerBase
    {
        IProductManager _productMananger;

        public ProductionController(IProductManager productMananger)
        {
            _productMananger = productMananger;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok(_productMananger.GetProducts());
        }
    }
}
```

Product manager

```
namespace RecipesApi.Business.Managers
{
    public class ProductManager : IProductManager
    {
        private IProductHeaderRepository _prodRep;
        public ProductManager(IProductHeaderRepository productHeaderRepository)
        {
            _prodRep=productHeaderRepository;
        }

        public ProductHeader GetProducts()
        {
            var x=_prodRep.FindById(1);
            return x ;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally ProductHeaderRepo and BaseRepo

```
public class ProductHeaderRepository : BaseRepository<ProductHeader>, IProductHeaderRepository
    {
        public ProductHeaderRepository(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            recipesContext = context;
            dbSet = context.Set<ProductHeader>();
        }
        protected DbContext recipesContext;
        protected DbSet<ProductHeader> dbSet;

        
    }
 
namespace RecipesApi.Data.Repositories
{
    public abstract class BaseRepository<TEnity>:IRepository<TEnity>
        where TEnity : class
    {
       protected DbContext recipesContext;
        protected DbSet<TEnity> dbSet;

        public BaseRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
            recipesContext = context;
            dbSet=context.Set<TEnity>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the by id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
        /// <returns>A TEnity.</returns>
        public TEnity FindById(int id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }
    }
}
```

And last part AppDbContext

```
namespace RecipesApi.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the product headers.
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<ProductHeader> ProductHeaders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In advance thx for all kind of help

Comment: Your `GetProducts` tries to return a single hard-coded ID. The other classes only add noise without helping - actually that "repository" is an *anti*patter (aka very bad idea). A DbSet is already a single-entity Repository. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. You aren't abstracting data access, EF Core does that - all you'd need to connect to MySQL or SQLite would be to change EF Core's config. If you wanted to abstract even EF, eg because now you want to use MongoDB, you already have ProductManager.

Comment: Get your code to work first and only then think whether you need any abstractions to solve real problems. That means, inject the DbContext into ProductManager and remove the useless "repository" classes. I'd bet there are other methods in there that break EF Core's transaction logic by executing a SaveChanges after every modification. Even ProductManager may not be needed in a small application, if all it does is map calls to the DbContext

Comment: In fact, to get your code to work *remove* ProductManager as well, and only inject AppDbContext into the controller. You'll see it works just fine, which means the problem was all those other classes. You don't need to have only one DbContext per application. You can have multiple DbContexts, to handle different scenarios.